# Web scraping with urllib.request - data is not refreshing

Tags: python, html, parsing, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to read a table on a website.  The first (initial) read is correct, but the subsequent requests in the loop are out of date (the information doesn't change even though the website changes).  Any suggestions?

*The link shown in the code is not the actual website that I am looking at.*  Also, I am going through proxy server.

I don't get an error, just out of date information.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import urllib.request
from pprint import pprint
from html_table_parser.parser import HTMLTableParser
import pandas as pd

def url_get_contents(url):
    #making request to the website
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=url)
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return f.read()

link='https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'    
xhtml = url_get_contents(link).decode('utf-8')
p = HTMLTableParser()
p.feed(xhtml)
stored_page=p.tables[0]

while True:
    try:

        xhtml = url_get_contents(link).decode('utf-8')
        p = HTMLTableParser()
        p.feed(xhtml)
        print('now: ',p.tables[0] )
        time.sleep(120)
        continue

    # To handle exceptions
    except Exception as e:
        print("error")
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors here.  Perhaps you're mistaken about the website content changing? But you haven't shown us that process, so there's no way for us to investigate that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `urllib` instead of `requests`?

Comment: `Also, I am going through proxy server.` Do you go through the same proxy when you visit the page in your browser?  Proxies may cache web pages, so you may be receiving a cached version instead of the most recent one.

Comment: I'm sure the website is changing.  I have some print statements in my code and the text is the same over and over.

Comment: I can try using requests.  It looks like I would have to use requests along with Beautiful Soup to get the table I need